# Is it possible to filter files by size using FileNameFilter interface in java

Tags: java

I know I can use the `FileFilter` interface to do what I want, but I have an exercice that somehow requires me to filter files by size using `FileNameFilter` implementation.

I have here a simple code, I give a directory and the code should technically filter the files in this directory and give me only the files that ends with ".exe" and that have a specific size. However I couldn't do the size filter with `FileNameFilter` because it checks the size of the Directory I sent not the files inside of it.

My implementation of FileNameFilter:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class MyFileFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    private String x;
    private int size;

    public MyFileFilter(String x, int size){
        this.x = x;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        //i can't use the dir.length because it checks the size of the directory and not the inside files
        return name.endsWith(x); // && dir.length() == size;
    }
}
```

and main:

```
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Emucef\\Downloads\\Programs");
MyFileFilter mff = new MyFileFilter(".exe", 9142656);
File[] list = f.listFiles(mff);
```

So basically the question is: is there a way to filter files by size using `FileNameFilter`, if so, how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    File file = new File(dir, name);
    return name.endsWith(x) && file.length() == size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        //i can't use the dir.length because it checks the size of the directory and not the inside files
        if(name.endsWith(x))
        {
            File f = new File(dir.getPath(), name);
            return f.length() == size;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your class to check it:

```
static class MyFileFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    private String x;
    private int size;

    public MyFileFilter(String x, int size){
        this.x = x;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        try {
            return (name.endsWith(x) && Files.size(Paths.get(dir.getPath(), name)) == size);                
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

`java.nio.file.Path` is part of the more modern `java.nio.file` lib, and does everything `java.io.File` does.

`java.nio.file.Path` is suggested to use for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

Using FileFiler instead of FilenameFilter would be more appropriate for what you intend to achieve. Your filter class would then look like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;

public class MyFileFilter implements FileFilter {
    private String x;
    private int size;

    public MyFileFilter(String x, int size){
        this.x = x;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.endsWith(x) && file.length() == size;
    }
}
```